# How can I use pulseaudio over ssh?

Tags: ssh, pulseaudio

I'd like to listen to music on my home server from work. Both are Ubuntu boxes running pulseaudio. It seems from researching that applications communicate to the PA server via TCP on port 4317, so I figured it should be as easy as:

```
me@work: ssh -YR 4317:localhost:4317 me@home
```

At this point I can run rhythmbox from the ssh session with X11 forwarding, and I assumed rhythmbox would be transparently talking to pulseaudio over the reverse tunnel, resulting in the music playing on my work machine. However instead it appears that the music still plays on my home computer. I've tried messing around with PULSE_SERVER as well to no avail.

Has anyone accomplished something similar? It seems like this should be relatively simple due to pulseaudio's design. I've played around with mounting my music library via sshfs instead but I'd really like to have one set of metadata/app settings/playlists and such. Thanks for any tips!

Comment: sounds like rhythmbox either isn't configured to play via pulseaudio (from what I know it goes via gstreamer so I'm not really sure where this config setting would be), or its connecting to a local pulseaudio server rather than your tunnel (if pulseaudio is already running on 'home', then have you checked your port redirection is even getting set up properly?)

Comment: I have no answer but `paman` might be able to help you. It's a configuration tool for pulseaudio. Theoretically on the side with rhythmbox you should change the stream to go through the network (with the help of device chooser or `pavucontrol`) and I have no idea what to do on receiving end.

Comment: This sounds like an awesome idea, but won't the bandwidth requirements be too high for most people's home broadband to cope?

Comment: Have you checked all of the issues mentioned here: http://www.pulseaudio.org/wiki/FAQ#HowdoIusePulseAudiooverthenetwork

Comment: Have you enabled networked PulseAudio in paprefs?

Comment: I feel like half the comments here are actually answers, and some of the answers actually ask questions!